# Filling missing values after grouping in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, plot, missing-data

The data looks like this:

```
         Unnamed: 0   userid  placeid              datetime
0                 0     1338   482954  2011-06-23T02:24:22Z   
1                 1     1338   580963  2011-06-22T14:23:03Z   
2                 2     1338   365256  2011-06-09T23:29:30Z   
3                 3     1338    89504  2011-05-22T15:54:30Z   
4                 4     1338  1267135  2011-05-21T16:51:13Z   
5                 5     1338  1487647  2011-05-16T18:40:41Z   
6                 6     1338   730343  2011-05-16T18:39:46Z   
7                 7     1338   365256  2011-04-24T17:13:13Z   
8                 8     1338  6394522  2011-04-24T13:51:04Z   
9                 9     1338    39597  2011-04-06T14:39:58Z
```

I have grouped the data by datetime (each month) and also userid. Then I have counted how many instances were in the given period per user. The result looks like this:

```
             Unnamed: 0  count
Date    userid                                      
2009-01 1                18       
        2                 4       
        3                 4       
        5                 3       
        7                 2       
        12               11       
2009-02 1                42       
        2               138      
        3                62      
        4                 6      
        5                58      
        6                 9      
        7                14
```

As you can see, there are some userids that are in 2009-01, not present in 2009-02, and vice versa. Since I am going to plot the counts, I need to have all users in both plots to be able to compare the two plots. Therefore, the desired output would be as follows (added rows are marked by *********):

```
             Unnamed: 0  count
Date    userid                                      
2009-01 1                18       
        2                 4       
        3                 4       
        4                 0     **********  
        5                 3
        6                 0     **********         
        7                 2       
        12               11       
2009-02 1                42       
        2               138      
        3                62      
        4                 6      
        5                58      
        6                 9      
        7                14 
        12                0      **********
```

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unstack the dataframe (the missing values shall become `na`'s), then fill the missing values with 0s, and stack the frame back again:

```
df.unstack().fillna(0).astype(int).stack()
```